# How to perform sum between two python class instances and get the list of length of every instance variable

Tags: python, sum, addition

Here is my problem.

I have to sum two instances of the class `Foo`. The class accepts the instance variable `bar` as `list`. My goal is to calculate during the addition, besides the sum (in the `list` sense), another list containing the length of every `instance.bar`.
Of course what I achieved till now does not work for sums involving more than two addenda, because it will always provide a list having length of 2.

Every help is really appreciated.

Here is my code so far.

```py
class Foo():

    def __init__(self, bar: list):
        if isinstance(bar, list):
            self.bar = bar
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"{bar} is not a list")  

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Foo):
            added_bar = self.bar + other.bar
            added_foo = Foo(added_bar)
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"{other} is not an instance of 'Foo'")
        added_foo.len_bars = [len(self.bar)] + [len(other.bar)]
        return added_foo

    def __radd__(self, other):
        if other == 0:
            return self
        else:
            return self.__add__(other)

a = Foo([1, 2, 3])
b = Foo([4, 5])
c = Foo([7, 8, 9, "a"])

r = a+b+c
print(r.len_bars) # prints [5, 4], is there a way to have [3, 2, 4]?
```

Comment: How do you get the results?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your question

Comment: Why do only some `Foo` instances have a `len_bars` attribute? Why is this not set in the constructor?

Comment: Basically, how exactly does the addition works? You can't just say "Here are the results" and expect us to know what you're talking about.

Comment: Because I need `len_bars` only in the summed instance to perform next tasks. Plus if the instance has the attr `len_bars` I immediately recognize that instance as the result of a sum

Comment: Furthermore, if `len_bars` was set in the constructor, when performing the sum as described in the code snippet I would end up having always one `int` (i.e. `len(self.bar)`), which is undesirable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to include the lengths in an add if they haven't been included before or include the previous list of lengths in an add if they had been included before. I updated the code.

```
class Foo():

    def __init__(self, bar: list):
        if isinstance(bar, list):
            self.bar = bar
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"{bar} is not a list")  

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Foo):
            added_bar = self.bar + other.bar
            added_foo = Foo(added_bar)
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"{other} is not an instance of 'Foo'")
        self_len_bars      = self.len_bars  if hasattr(self,'len_bars')  else [len(self.bar)]
        other_len_bars     = other.len_bars if hasattr(other,'len_bars') else [len(other.bar)]
        added_foo.len_bars = self_len_bars + other_len_bars
        return added_foo

    def __radd__(self, other):
        if other == 0:
            return self
        else:
            return self.__add__(other)

a = Foo([1, 2, 3])
b = Foo([4, 5])
c = Foo([7, 8, 9, "a"])

r = a+b+c
print(r.len_bars)
```